# ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, importerror, django-rest-auth

I imported `from rest_auth.views import LoginView` and I'm trying to implement login API. I never import `ugettext_lazy` directly.

```py
from rest_auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from .serializers import LoginUserSerializer

class Login(LoginView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = LoginUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)
        return super().post(request, format=None)
```

But I got the error below:

```
File "filePath\ProjectName\app1\urls.py", line 4, in <module> from .login
import Login 
File "filePath\ProjectName\app1\login.py", line 1, in <module> from
rest_auth.views import LoginView  
File "\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_auth\views.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _ ImportError:
cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation' (\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py)
```

I read the other answers and most of the answers suggested downgrading from Django version 4 to 3.

Are there any other ways to fix this problem or any other suggestions to implement login API?

Edit: I used `simple jwt` to implement the token based authentication.

Comment: rest_auth does not support Django 4.0.x. `ugettext_lazy` removed from Django 4.0.x

Comment: Please check the github issues section of rest-auth. 
https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/650#issuecomment-1023757435

Answer (score 2):

`pip` is installing `django 4` by default, and `django-user-session` doesn't seems to be compatible with `Django 4.0` which does not have `ugettext_lazy`

You can fix the issue by downgrading the version of `django` to 3.2 until 4.0 is properly supported.

```bash
pip install django==3.2
```

This is a temporary workaround for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**ugettext_lazy** has been removed in Django 4. I am used ***gettext_lazy*** instead:
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

Answer (score 0):

Install [this](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth) instead then import from `dj_rest_auth`

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) will solve the error:

```
pip install django-rest-auth --upgrade
```

Comment: doesn't solve the problem